# Is there a way to open and run a complete ML project in kaggle notebooks just like in google colab?

Tags: machine-learning, gpu, google-colaboratory, kaggle

I have my complete ML project on colab. But i want to shift to kaggle. **Does kaggle allows a way to upload an entire project folder and let you traverse through the code files?** Similar to how colab lets you mount and then you can traverse through your project folder.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you can simply compress your project directory into a zip file ... and upload the zip file as a dataset, then launch a kernel from there.  Just keep in mind everything is read only unless you are in kaggle/working/